# After reinstallation, Disk Cleanup disappears when I click OK

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, disk-cleanup

After I reinstalled Windows 7, Disk Cleanup stopped working.
I can start Disk Cleanup and select the drive to clean, but when I click on the OK button, the window disappears.

Any solutions?

Here's the data from Windows Logs>Application :-

```
EventData  
1744235005     
1   

APPCRASH  
Not available  
 0  
 cleanmgr.exe  
 6.1.7600.16385  
 4a5bc5e1   
Csi.dll  
 14.0.4733.1000  
 4b5662be  
 c0000005   
00135213  

F:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Local\Temp\WER419.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

F:\Users\Jacob\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_cleanmgr.exe
```

The above one was with an Information icon.

The one below was with an Error icon:--

```
EventData

   cleanmgr.exe   
   6.1.7600.16385   
   4a5bc5e1   
   Csi.dll   
   14.0.4733.1000   
   4b5662be   
   c0000005   
   00135213   
   bbc   
   01cbd5be36b572bf   
   F:\Windows\system32\cleanmgr.exe   
   F:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\Csi.dll   
   75fa9599-41b1-11e0-b864-001966b2bcb6
```

I also used process explorer:

When I started disk cleanup, a cleanmgr.exe process appeared under explorer.exe.But when I clicked on the "OK" button after selecting the drive, cleanmgr.exe was there for some seconds before it disappeared. But a new process - WerFault.exe appeared under svchost.exe a few seconds after I clicked the "OK" button. It disappeared, too, from the process list after some time (I think it disappeared along with cleanmgr.exe).

---

Oh yeah btw. After reinstalling Windows I merged the previous Windows and users folders with the new ones because I thought my Internet connection settings were stored in the old ones. But I had done this before and there was no problem with cleanmgr. I actually reinstalled Windows 7, 3 times before. No problems at that time. This time I accidentally deleted my old useful user account files.So I recovered some of them with "Recover My Files". Then since my Internet wasnt working I merged my old Windows files with the new one and even kept the duplicates with suffix (2)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are better of reinstalling or using alternatives, you'll *waste* more time on troubleshooting!

I could get you started on [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), [Windows Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default), [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor), [WinDBG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx), etc...;
but I do not see a point in trying to go through all those hurdles and analysis if your install went wrong.

---

**Update:**

Using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653), I figured out the command line ran when you click OK:

```
C:\Users\TomWij\AppData\Local\Temp\X\dismhost.exe {Y}
```

Where X and Y are [GUIDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).

Exactly this seem to happen after clicking OK:

1. A Temp folder is made, a GUID X guarantees this folder is random.
2. A [Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371719(v=vs.85).aspx) is extracted to this folder.
3. The DISM tool in instructed to start the dialog to clean the hard drive that has GUID Y.

The only two things I can think of that are wrong when running this program in your case is, with [PM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645):

- **ACCESS DENIED** file events on the Temp folder, fix your permissions.
- **ACCESS DENIED** file events on the drive you try to clean, are you running as administrator?

Or perhaps **DISM is broken**, try `sfc /scannow` to see if this fixes something.

Also, check your Task Manager to see if it's a hanging process and your event logs for errors.

Comment: @TomWij- Thanks a lot for your help. I tried sfc /scannow and it returned "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations." I tried viewing event logs and yes, there were errors whenever i ran Disk Cleanup. I edited my post to include more information. Please check it out.

Comment: oh yeah btw.....after reinstalling windows i merged the previous windows and users folders with the new ones coz i thought my internet connection settings were stored in the old ones. But i had done this before and there was no problem with cleanmgr. I actually reinstalled windows 7, 3 times before. No problems at that time. This time i accidentally deleted my old useful user account files.So i recovered some of them with "Recover My Files". Then since my internet wasnt working i merged my old windows files with the new one and even kept the duplicates with suffix (2).

Comment: @James: There should be a file that ends with .mdmp next to the wer file, that's the only file I would need to troubleshoot the exact issue. BUT, with the recent information you gave me it makes sense why you get this error: The permissions on the folders disk clean-up needs to access are overwritten (explains the ACCESS VIOLATION), so as said Process Monitor will be the fastest way to determine which permissions need to be corrected.

Comment: @James: **IMPORTANT NOTICE**: Overwriting your new installation with files from your previous installation is a very bad thing to do, you simply are overwriting ALL registry/user permissions and settings. This diminishes the effect of your re-installation and brings in a lot of incorrectness, as your computer would be looking for things that are no longer there or your computer might not have access to specific things anymore as seen with disk clean-up. Do you really need to get the internet connection settings from there? Because it's quite a mess this way...

Comment: @Tom - well i dont understand how, but i couldnt get your replies after my last post on feb 28. today, on 11th may i saw this question again and surprisingly it says that you replied me twice on the same day!